# systemClock.sleep() not working properly

Tags: android

I am trying to make my activity sleep for 1 second before drawing text but it is not working. The application is pausing for a second then drawing everything in the if block at once. It is executing both the code above and below the call to systemClock.sleep(ms) after the ms seconds:

my if statement code block is below:

```
    if(xClick<getPaddingLeft()+squareWidth && 
      yClick<getPaddingTop()+squareWidth)
    {
        if(firstMove)one="X";
        canvas.drawText(one, getPaddingLeft()+squareWidth/2, 
  getPaddingTop()+(float)0.65*squareWidth, xPaint);
        if(firstMove)
            {
            SystemClock.sleep(3000);
            canvas.drawText("O", getPaddingLeft()+squareWidth+squareWidth/2, 
  getPaddingTop()+(float)0.65*squareWidth, xPaint);
            }
        two="O";
        firstMove=false;
        drawMoveOne=true;
    }
```

Comment: You are not seeing the *result* of the drawing until after that number of milliseconds, because you are preventing Android from doing the actual work until after that number of milliseconds. Android does not draw text when you call `drawText()`. Android *plans* to draw text when you call `drawText()`. The actual drawing will not occur until you return control back to Android, by returning from whatever callback you are in.

Comment: In addition to what CommonsWare said-  never sleep on the main thread.  You're preventing any work from being done by any part of the framework.

Comment: thanks. I have used the systemClock.sleep() method on a background thread before in an AsyncTask class